# Checkbox Ajax return post

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, checkbox

I have been struggling with this for a while. I know there are multiple posts about this but since I am new to the subject I am struggling to understand. I would like to post the values of a my checkbox forms to php script and return the value of the values back to a div on my page. Here is the code :

onclick function with ajax call :

```
    <script>
    function submit_form(){
    var data = { 'saqalinproxy[]' : []};
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
    var chck1 = $(this).val();
    alert(chck1);
    data['saqalinproxy[]'].push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'testdeploy.php',
    data : data,
    dataType: "html",
    success : function(data){
          $('#progress_status').hide();
          $('.return').html(data); // replace the contents coming from php file
            }
        });
          $('#progress_status').show();
   }
   </script>
```

HTML Form :

```
<div style="width: 700px; height: 150px; padding: 10px">
<form id="caForm" class="caForm" method="post" name="caForm">
<fieldset id="fs-0">
<legend>QA Proxy Servers</legend>
<input type="checkbox" id="saqalin-proxy01" name="saqalinproxy[]" value="41.191.126.246">saqalin-proxy01<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="saqalin-proxy02" name="saqalinproxy[]" value="41.191.126.247">saqalin-proxy02<br><br>
<!--<input type="checkbox" id="ca-0"> Check/Uncheck All -->
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Deploy" onclick="submit_form();"/>

</fieldset>
</form>

</div>

<div id="status">
<p style="display:none;" id="progress_status"><img id="progress_image_status" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt=""> Checking if this kak works!</p>
</div>

<div id="return"></div>
```

PHP Post Page :

```
<?

    if(isset($_POST['saqalinproxy[]'])){
        $invite = $_POST['saqalinproxy[]'];
        print_r($invite);
    }

?>
```

I am struggling to get the values returned on my page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$('.return')` there is no class as `return`, pl change this into `$('#return')`. Still if it's not working means post your php code

Comment: alert `data` variable after success function and check what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

On this line you are selecting an element with a class of `return` because the `.` denotes a classname:

```
$('.return').html(data);
```

In your HTML, your `div` has an `id` of `return` not a class (note the `#`). So change it to:

```
$('#return').html(data);
```

Your second problem is in the PHP code, you are trying to target the posted array with `$_POST['saqalinproxy[]']`. PHP parses it directly to a PHP array so `$_POST['saqalinproxy']` is actually the array.

```
 if(isset($_POST['saqalinproxy'])){
    $invite = $_POST['saqalinproxy'];
```

For example, if both items are checked then:

```
echo $_POST['saqalinproxy'][0]; // outputs 41.191.126.246
echo $_POST['saqalinproxy'][1]; // outputs 41.191.126.247
```

Also, instead of trying to build the post data like you are, you can simply serialize the form:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'testdeploy.php',
    data : $('#caForm').serialize(),
```

When you get those problems fixed, you'll see that the form is submitting twice. The first time as ajax, then second as a traditional request. To resolve that you need to return false in the onclick or return false from the function..

```
<input type="submit" value="Deploy" onclick="submit_form(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: ok changed to $('#return').html(data); which I had originally actually still no luck. The alert gives me the correct data - Im not sure if Im posting to the script correctly or if its recieving the data correctly...?

Comment: Ok great. Firebug is showing that posts are working fine and the correct data : html and response is posting but I am struggling to get the data returned into the div...

Comment: Does the PHP code output the expected result? If you don't check any of the checkboxes, they won't be received by the PHP end.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Yeah I have added the return false. The php that Im am posting to just has :

      echo $_POST['saqalinproxy'][0];
      echo $_POST['saqalinproxy'][1];

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all your help. The mechanics is all working correctly and that is good enough for now. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, update the question with what it's doing now/not doing and I'll have a look.,

Answer (score 0):

few changes in both html js and php. In html

```
<input type="submit" value="Deploy" onclick="return submit_form();"/>
```

In js  return false in submit_form function.
And in php

```
if(isset($_POST['saqalinproxy'])){
    $invite = $_POST['saqalinproxy'];
    print_r($invite);
}
```

also change `$('.return').html(data); to $('#return').html(data);`

Comment: you are not able to see response as page was refreshing after submit return false will prevent page from refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

you may use a library that makes that automatically for you, that is phery http://phery-php-ajax.net, in your case, it would be like this (notice the `data-remote="deploy"` on the form)

```html
<div style="width: 700px; height: 150px; padding: 10px">
    <form id="caForm" class="caForm" data-remote="deploy" action="testdeploy.php" name="caForm">
        <fieldset id="fs-0">
            <legend>QA Proxy Servers</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" id="saqalin-proxy01" name="saqalinproxy[]" value="41.191.126.246">saqalin-proxy01<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="saqalin-proxy02" name="saqalinproxy[]" value="41.191.126.247">saqalin-proxy02<br><br>
            <!--<input type="checkbox" id="ca-0"> Check/Uncheck All -->
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Deploy" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="status">
    <p style="display:none;" id="progress_status"><img id="progress_image_status" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt=""> Checking if this kak works!</p>
</div>

<div id="return"></div>
```

then in your `testdeploy.php` you would change it to:

```php
function deploy($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse;
  foreach ($data['saqalinproxy'] as $proxy){
    // do whatever you need to do with $proxy here
  }
  $r->jquery('#return')->html('set the HTML of your return');
  $r->jquery('#progress_status')->hide();
  return $r;
}

Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'deploy' => 'deploy'
))->process();
```

That's it, no need for additional Javascript code, it's all automatic. But to show the progress, you'd do:

```js
$(function(){
  // phery:before fires before sending the AJAX
  $('#caForm').bind('phery:before', function(){
    $('#progress_status').show();
  });
});
```